# Will the dialog box( with jQuery) disappear on a Click event in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I created a dialog box with a jQuery. However, When I click the button the dialog box disappears in a few seconds. My button has a click event registered to it. I think my button for some reason is posting back hence reloading the page but I am not sure why this is happening or what actually is happening.

Can someone please explain me this issue?
Jquery:

```
$(function () {
         $("#dialog").dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             show: {
                 effect: "bounce",
                 duration: 1000000000
             },

         });

         $("#opener").click(function () {
             $("#dialog").dialog("open");
         });
     });
```

Dialog Code:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Select the records which you want to combine">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Comments"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="59px" 
        style="margin-left: 13px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="303px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Combine" />

</div>
<asp:Button ID="opener" runat="server" Text="Combine" 
    onclick="Button2_Click" />
```

Answer (score 2):

by default the buttons are submit buttons.  Add type="button" to your buttons.

And, your button is defined as runat="server" and has a server onclick event, so of course it must be doing a postback to the server.

just use a regular html button

```
<button id="opener" type="button>Combine</button>
```

Comment: If I remove runat Server I am geting attribute present on the tag error

Comment: Instead can I change the code inside jQuery? I mean keeping the type as submit the handling it inside the jquery?

Comment: @Geoff I want "Visible" property, which I can get in ``<asp:button></asp:Button>`` but not in ``<button></button>``. What should I do? (I've constraints to make Visible=true)

Comment: @Rahman - add the style attribute: <button style="display:none"></button> or better yet, add a CSS class <button class="hidden"></button> <style>.hidden { display: none }</style>